# Setting data in a nested fieldset collection in zend 2 - Returns empty (parent fieldset works)

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I have a nested fieldset collection **item** inside another fieldset **Ill** that I am trying to set element variables for. I can successfully set elements for the **Ill** fieldset but am unable to generate or **item** fieldsets within the collection.

I have a very similar layout to this example: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html

The layout of nested forms is:
ILLForm(Form)->Ill(FieldSet)->Item(Collection/Fieldsets)
(the Ill can have many Item fieldsets)

Here is the Indexcontroller:

```
        $ill = new Ill('ill', $this->ILLCategories, $this->campuses, $this->getFromOptions);

        $ill->setName($session->name);
        $ill->setEmail($session->email);

        $item_array = array();

        if ( isset($session->department))
        {
            $ill->setDepartment($session->department);
            $ill->setDivision($session->division);
           if ( isset($session->formData->items))
           {
               $item_iterator = $session->formData->items;
               $i = -1;
               foreach ( $item_iterator as $item)
               {
                   $i++;
                   $item_fieldset = new Item('Item '.($i+1), $this->ILLCategories, $this->getFromOptions);
                   $item_fieldset->setILLType($item->ILLType);
                   $item_fieldset->setGetFrom($item->getFrom);
                   $item_array[] = $item_fieldset;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               $item_fieldset = new Item('Item 1', $this->ILLCategories, $this->getFromOptions);
               $item_array[] = $item_fieldset;
           }

        }
        else
        {
            $item_fieldset = new Item('Item 1', $this->ILLCategories, $this->getFromOptions);
            $item_array[] = $item_fieldset;

        }

        $ill->items = $item_array;
        $this->ILLForm->bind( $ill );
```

When I view the result in the view controller no items appear. Here is an example of the data I am trying to bind to the fieldsets:

```
object(ILL\Entity\Ill)[452]
  protected 'name' => string 'Test' (length=4)
  protected 'email' => string 'yay@yay.com' (length=11)
  protected 'division' => string 'Test' (length=4)
  protected 'department' => string 'Test' (length=4)
  protected 'contact' => null
  protected 'phone' => null
  protected 'idNumber' => null
  protected 'campus' => null
  public 'item' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(ILL\Entity\Item)[453]
          private 'ILLType' => null
          private 'requiredBy' => null
          private 'urgent' => null
          private 'citation' => null
          private 'copyright' => null
          private 'getFrom' => null
```

It could be something simple that I have overlooked in the way I have structured the data but it eludes me.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes? Is it something that obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it seems the **bind()** function does not set the nested fieldset collections (but does everything else).

There is another function that does not have this issue called **setData()**. I basically changed this part of the code:

```
$this->ILLForm->bind( $ill );
```

to this:

```
//   If previously submitted then run the validation to generate messages, otherwise bind autogenerated data to form (username etc...)
if ( isset($session->formData))
{
    $this->ILLForm->setData($session->formData);
    $this->ILLForm->isValid($ill);                           
}
else
{
    $this->ILLForm->bind($ill);
}
```

As per the comment in the code, if there is a session set then the data is pushed into the fields via the **setData()** function (and then validated).
If its a fresh load then the model is bound to the fields via the **bind()** function.